# Logic App initialize array from other variables

Tags: azure-logic-apps

What's the correct syntax to initialize an array variable with elements from other variables? I tried:

```
"Initialize_variable_AllEventCounts": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "AllEventCounts",
                            "type": "Array",
                            "value": "[@{variables('EmailConfirmedFailureEventCount')}, @{variables('EmailConfirmedSuccessEventCount')}, @{variables('UserCreatedEventCount')}, @{variables('UserLoginFailureEventCount')}, @{variables('UserLoginSuccessEventCount')}, @{variables('UserLogoutSuccessEventCount')}]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Set_variable_EmailConfirmedFailureEventCount": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Set_variable_EmailConfirmedSuccess": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Set_variable_UserCreatedEventCount": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Set_variable_UserLoginFailureEventCount": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Set_variable_UserLoginSuccessEventCount": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Set_variable_UserLogoutSuccessEventCount": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
```

There's also a `createArray()` expression that didn't provide the result that I expected:

```
"value": "@{createArray(variables('EmailConfirmedFailureEventCount'), variables('EmailConfirmedSuccessEventCount'), variables('UserCreatedEventCount'), variables('UserLoginFailureEventCount'), variables('UserLoginSuccessEventCount'), variables('UserLogoutSuccessEventCount'))}"
```

---

**UPDATE:**
The above createArray() syntax was close to correct. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
"value": "@createArray(variables('EmailConfirmedFailureEventCount'), variables('EmailConfirmedSuccessEventCount'), variables('UserCreatedEventCount'), variables('UserLoginFailureEventCount'), variables('UserLoginSuccessEventCount'), variables('UserLogoutSuccessEventCount'))"
```

Comment: Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward. The createArray() expression works as expected. It must have been some other syntax error in my larger Logic App that was confusing me to think there was a syntax error in my array initialization.

To answer my own question, I created an empty Logic App to test this single thing:
[image: The logic app designer]

And the complete code for that sample Logic App is as follows:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_Array1_=_[Var1,_Var2]": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Array1",
                            "type": "Array",
                            "value": "@createArray(variables('Var1'), variables('Var2'))"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Var2_=_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Var1_=_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Var1",
                            "type": "Integer",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Var2_=_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Var2",
                            "type": "Integer",
                            "value": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Var1_=_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the output from a successful run:
[image: The output from a successful run]

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Union action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#union), you could use it to combine multiple arrays.

```
"Initialize_variable_4": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "array4",
                        "type": "Array",
                        "value": "@union(variables('array1'),variables('array2'),variables('array3'))"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_variable_3": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        }
```

[image]

Comment: So if "test3", "value3" and 4 weren't hard typed like in that sample, but values of existing variables, how would you initialize array3 then?

Comment: @Eivind Gussiås Løkseth, yes this way is to combine multiple arrays value to one array.  What do you mean 'how would you initialize array3 then'? And what  format you want?

Comment: Did you want `[[array1],[array2]]`?  If you want this format, whan you initialize an array in the value just set with `[variable('array1'),variable('array2')]`.

Comment: And my arry4 is combined with three arrays,  the values just like one array without `[]` to separate them.

Comment: Hi! It's a correct answer for joining two arrays. I've provided my own answer below. I created a new simple logic app to isolate the problem.

Comment: @Eivind Gussiås Løkseth, if that you could mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Yes, I will in a few hours. It blocked for 24 hours after answering your own questions.